# How to Set Collectionview cell margin in all layout

Tags: ios, view, uicollectionview

**This is perfect output for iPhone 5s and 4**

[image]

**And Iphone 6s output as**

[image]

**I need all devices same layout look like iPhone 5**

Comment: are you using custom collectionview or by storyboard?

Comment: i using storyboard

Comment: you can easily set collectionview's property from size inspector